# LINQ Group By Wrong Results

Tags: c#, sql, linq

My table

```
userid                                       UserApproveLevel_Two_T
1118bda4-6cba-43d6-a0cd-555555555555               True
22299872-aa01-498a-831d-555555555555               False
333a8ddb-d261-47d9-8ec8-555555555555               False
```

-

```
 var sky = DB.UserSkypeTrackers.GroupBy(x => x.UserApproveLevel_Two_T == true).FirstOrDefault();
```

-

```
 foreach (var item in sky )
  {
       // in here    i see  
       //22299872-aa01-498a-831d-555555555555
       //333a8ddb-d261-47d9-8ec8-555555555555        
  }
```

-

i should be seeing

> 1118bda4-6cba-43d6-a0cd-555555555555

in my foreach

why i see false results??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) method in LINQ to Objects preserves the order of the groupings, as per the docs:

> The `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>` objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in `source` that produced the first key of each `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>`. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in `source`.

Which is probably what you expected to see `111...`.

***However,*** you seem to be using `GroupBy` on a database table or something like that. This means that you are using [`Queryable.GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupBy__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___). According to *its* docs,

> The query behavior that occurs as a result of executing an expression tree that represents calling `GroupBy<TSource,TKey>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>>)` depends on the implementation of the type of the source parameter. The expected behavior is that it groups the elements of source by a key value that is obtained by invoking keySelector on each element.

As you can see, the exact behaviour is implementation specific, and it doesn't have to preserve the order. Therefore, the first `IGrouping` is not necessarily the group with the key `true`.

So to get your desired results, either:

- use `Where` to find the group with the key `true`, or
- Load all the objects into memory first, then use LINQ to Object's `GroupBy`. (This could be slow if you have a lot of objects in the database)

Comment: i dont understand a lot from this document.  But thanks anyway.

Comment: @cirtizumle You don't need to understand everything. You just need to understand the "depends on the implementation of the type of the source parameter. " part, which means that your database system gets to decide how to group by your objects, and it doesn't have to be in the order of the keys.

Comment: but, group by not bringing all results, it brings the ones i don't want. If I write x.UserApproveLevel_Two_T == false ( opposite one), it will bring the desired object.

Comment: @cirtizumle Here's a bold guess, which might be wrong: your database sorts the groups in the natural order of their keys, so a key of `false` always comes before a key of `true`. I think you have a misunderstanding of how `GroupBy` works. `GroupBy` brings all your data. It's `FirstOrDefault` that removes all your data except the first group.

Answer (score 0):

`GroupBy()` groups the element present in List based on specified pradicates. In your case you are trying to get elements whose `UserApproveLevel_Two_T` property set to `True`,

Instead of `GroupBy()`, you can use `Where()` clause to achieve expected result

```
 var sky = DB.UserSkypeTrackers.Where(x => x.UserApproveLevel_Two_T).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Bonus :**

As you are checking condition against `bool` variable, no need to check `== true` condition, `.Where(x => x.UserApproveLevel_Two_T)` will work instead of `.Where(x => x.UserApproveLevel_Two_T == true)`

`sky` variable contains single record as you are calling `FirstOrDefault();` after where clause. Here `FirstOrDefault()` will return single element or default value from collection. So no need to iterate over `sky`

Comment: but, group by not bringing all results, it brings the ones i don't want. If I write x.UserApproveLevel_Two_T == false, it will bring the desired object.

Comment: @cirtizumle, it is giving you all records of false because you are grouping by bool value and then getting first record i.e. group of false elements

Comment: @cirtizumle, does it satisfies your query

Comment: thanks, you and Sweeper helped me a lot. I changed my query and now it works .
 Guid can_approve_one_plus_T_second_last_score = DB.UserSkypeTrackers.Where(x => x.Presence == "AVAILABLE" && x.UserApproveLevel_OnePlus_T == true).OrderBy(p => p.Score).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().UserID.Value;